# My OS secretly started using the wrong disk (initially clone of startup disk). How do I migrate relevant files?

Tags: macos

I'm on a mac running OS 10.10

2 weeks ago I installed an SSD in original bay (SATA 0?) and put the original HD in the optical drive bay.  I cloned the original HD and initially the thing was starting up from the SSD.  Now I've discovered that a few days ago, it secretly started up from the old disk! (which I had kept as a temporary backup in case the upgrade went awry).  So I've now got files spread over the two disks, including things managed by photo cataloging software, application support libraries, etc.

I just ran a find command (`find /Users/username/ -mtime -14`) to list stuff that is newer than the upgrade and there is lots of it.

How can I put the misplaced files into their correct location on the new disk?  I guess I want a script or command which at a high level does:
Move files created less than 14 days ago from /Users/username/* (but not in folders A, B, C) to /Volumes/New Disk/Users/username/

I didn't put this in the mac stack exchange because it could probably be answered by a unix person.

Comment: It sounds a little like a very big mess, but if it's not a million files, I'd be tempted to try a diff & GUI solution, something like kdiff to find different files, then move them over "by hand", but only if it's a small number of files. ps. `find` has the `-exec` option, and pairs great with `xargs`, just something like your find command followed by `| xargs cp --target-directory="/Volumes/New Disk/Users/username/" might work? Using find's `-print0` and xargs's `-0` should avoid funny filename problems

Comment: Thanks @Xen2050.  I would still need to avoid all kinds of temp files, probably by avoiding certain directories.  Maybe manual is the solution.  I did find out that the problem only started 3 days ago.

Comment: This is definitely *not* a Unix question, but an OS X question. The part where you've got "things managed by photo cataloging software, application support libraries, etc.," involved takes you far beyond a mere filesystem sync, manual or otherwise. Manual review at least lets you see what's scrambled, and decide whether it's worth digging deeper case-by-case ... and some will, and some won't, be worth it.